# How is a vector a representation?

Tags: representation-theory

I am working on a homework problem that gives the character table for the octahedral group O, and then asks to ``decompose the vector (x,y,z) into irreps of O''. What does this mean? How can a vector be a representation?

Comment: I think it referres to a set of three functions R3->R, namely $f1(x,y,z) = x$, $f2(x,y,z) = y$ and $f3(x,y,z) = z$. This functions can be transformed with the operations of the group, and you can build a representation of the group, which may or may not be irreducible.

Comment: The question does not seem to be well formulated; indeed one does not decompose vectors just like that. You need to supply more context to know what was meant; if an actual representation on a vector space was given it could be asking to write a vector as a sum of vectors in irreducible sub-representations, but if no representation is specified, your vector might need to be interpreted as a character, which you can then decompose into a sum of irreducible characters.

Comment: The second sentence of the statement is in parentheses: "The action of O symmetries on this vector defines a 3-dimensional representation; compute its characters." But O acting on a vector gives me a set of vectors - how is this related to a representation?

Answer (score 1):

Your vector space is a direct sum of the irreps, which means that your vector can be written uniquely as a sum of vectors from each irrep, which is what they want you to determine.

Comment: How is a vector space a direct sum of irreps? Representations are sets of matrices, vector spaces are sets of vectors...

How would I go about computing the characters of this representation?

Comment: Representations are $k$-linear maps from the group algebra $kG$ to $End(V)$ for some vector space $V$, in particular, $V$ is a $kG$-module.  Conversely, let $V$ be a $kG$-module (hence it is a $k$-vectorspace), then you can define a $k$-linear map from $kG$ to $End(V)$, hence a representation.  What this says is "representations and modules" are the same thing, and don't forget $kG$-modules are vectorspaces.